# Почему не работает вход через google?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Почему не работает вход через google?

Мой MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button googlesignin, fblogin, loginemail, loginphone;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user!=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        googlesignin = findViewById(R.id.googlesignin);
        fblogin = findViewById(R.id.fblogin);
        loginemail = findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
        loginphone = findViewById(R.id.loginphone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        createRequestGoogleSignIn();

        //Обработка нажатия кнопки авторизации google
        googlesignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createRequestGoogleSignIn() {
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...

                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Лог ошибок

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.buratinoapps.testauth, PID: 32294
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buratinoapps.testauth/com.buratinoapps.testauth.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.buratinoapps.testauth. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.buratinoapps.testauth. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:183)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.2:1)
        at com.buratinoapps.testauth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в логах написана причина ошибки и как её исправить:

> IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.buratinoapps.testauth. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Соответственно вызовите

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

в onCreate активити или, лучше, в Application классе.

Comment: Я добавил в onCreate FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); тоже самое происходит